# Apps Script webapp load Javascript (jQuery) in stages

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script, web-applications

I'm building a **webapp** using Google's Apps Script's HTML Service. I'm trying to optimize the loading of the app so that the user gets a faster experience.

One way I've been experimenting with is to load only the essential **html/css/javascript** that will display the login page, and while the user is typing in their credentials the app loads most of the app in the background. By the time the user clicks on Login, all the **html/css/javascript** (I'm using **jQuery**) has downloaded to the browser.

This seems to be working so far, and indeed improves the speed of loading a lot. However, any function that was loaded in batch 1 is no longer accessible if called from the javascript loaded in batch 2. In other words, reusing a function is not possible unless it's loaded in the same batch as the function that calls it.
Edit: The function throws an undefined error, which further suggests it has no access to the previously loaded batch of javascript. Edit: I assigned id 'loadJs' to the initial batch of js and then tried calling `alert($('#loadJs').html())` from the second batch of js. It's working fine, which means the script is still there in the browser, but for some reason calling specific functions from it is no longer possible...

Why does this happen, and what would be a way around this?

Edit: responding to a couple of comments to this thread –

Here is how I'm loading the **jQuery**:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

Regarding TheMaster suggesting to specify which function is not accessible – it doesn't seem to matter; any function that was loaded in batch 1 will not be accessible if called from a function loaded in batch 2. Here's a simple example – the following is a function in load.js (initial load, batch 1):

```
function testFunction() {
   alert('Hello');
}
```

When invoked by any function that's in the same batch, works as expected. Now this function is in notes.js (batch 2):

```
$('.hoverBtn').on('click', function () {
   try {
      testFunction();
   } catch (e) {
     alert(e.message);
   }
});
```

When I click the button, an alert pops up saying: 'testFunction is not defined', which means the 2nd batch js is working (the onClick fired) but there is no longer access to the function in batch 1 (testFunction).

*In case it proves useful to understand the context of the question, here's a step-by-step of how I'm loading the html/css/javascript in 2 stages. I may later try to consolidate the 2nd batch load into one `script.run`, but I don't think it's relevant to the question for now:

Initial app load is with `doGet()` in the .gs file:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('load')
  .evaluate()
  .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)
  .setTitle('title')
  .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1');
}
```

The file load.html contains the line `<?!= include('load_css'); ?>` at the beginning and `<?!= include('load_js'); ?>` at the end to include the 1st batches of css and js and is loaded with the `include()` function in the .gs file:

```
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
  .getContent();
}
```

The javascript is nested in `$(function(){})` so that it runs only when `load.html` if fully loaded.

load.html contains the `div` element that will be injected with the 2nd batch of html: `<div id='app_content' style='display:none'></div>`. The notes.html file (2nd html batch, where app_content is) contains the `div`s for the 2nd batches of css and js:

```
<div id='notes_css'></div>
<div id='notes_js'></div>
```

The last thing `load.js` runs is this:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(getNotes).include('notes');
```

`getNotes()` loads the new html and then calls another `script.run` to get the new css:

```
function getNotes(html) {
   $('#app_content').html(html);
   google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(getNotesCss).include('notes_css');
}
```

`getNotesCss()` loads the new css and then calls another `script.run` to get the new js:

```
function getNotesCss(html) {
   $notes_css = html;
   google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(getNotesJs).include('notes_js');
}
```

`getNotesJs()` loads the new js and sets var `$notes_js` as `true` (this is so the css is not injected in the `div` until the user clicks Login because the new css conflicts with the old):

```
function getNotesJs(html) {
   $('#notes_js').html(html);
   $notes_js = true;
}
```

When the user clicks the button to Login, the initial landing page (#ar_A) is hidden, and providing `vars $notes_js && $notes_css` are `true` (meaning data finished loading) it then sets the new css and shows #app_content. If the user was quick and the data hasn't fully loaded yet, it waits half a second and tries again, until successful:

```
function login() {
   $('#ar_A').hide();
   if ($notes_js && $notes_css) {
      $('#notes_css').html($notes_css);
      $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
      $('select').material_select();
      return $('#app_content').show();
   } else setTimeout(function(){
      login();
   }, 500);
}
```

Comment: Consider [Edit]ing to include Which function is not accessible and what makes you think that?

Comment: I don't see which jQ you're even loading in this post... Why wouldn't you include the relevant lines that specify the libraries you load?

Comment: Note that Google provides some cached versions of jQuery. Using these will very likely speed your loads and perhaps remove the need for work around you are attempting. https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery Also consider that you are probably replacing the top-level context. Have you tried using the `.withUserObject` method, e.g. perhaps the new and old can be combined? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#user_objects

Comment: @tehhowch thanks for the tip about the cached versions! I wasn't aware of that and updated my code. Having said that it doesn't change much in the loading speed, the app still takes a couple of extra seconds to load and it's those seconds that I'm trying to get around. Regarding `.withUserObject` – see my last edit; it seems the original script is still there, it's accessing the individual functions in it which becomes an issue.

Comment: Try moving `<div id='notes_js'></div> ` below the first batch js in loadhtml

Comment: @TheMaster Moving the `<div>` below didn't help.

Comment: Are the  global variables declared in first js(`window.test="testing.."`) accessible in second js (`alert(test)` or alert(window.test))?

Comment: @TheMaster Yes, I just checked and there is access in batch2 to global vars declared in bath1. Is that good news..?

Comment: Then just make  your function global. `window.testFunction=function () {
   alert('Hello');
}`

Comment: @TheMaster Yep! That works!! Many many thanks. Any idea why this might be happening though? Just curious.